# Jquery File uploader

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, ini

I am trying to upload large files using Blue Imp's Jquery File uploader and I have changed my post_max_size in and max_file_size to 80megs in my php.ini in Plesk (see screenshot) and I have changed the directive in the configuration file to :
`'max_file_size' => 75000000,`

but for some reason it will still only let me upload files up to 16 megs.

Is there another place I need to change the file size to be able to upload up to 75megs?

[image]

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` say? Are the new values you set up in Plesk there?

Comment: Yes.  Thank you.  I figured out what I was missing there is also a directive in a file called jquery.fileupload-validate.js that you also have to change

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone.  There is also a directive in a file called jquery.fileupload-validate.js max_file_size that needs to change.